# Javascript Window.Print Doesn't Work in Android or iOS using TWebBrowser (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I have a embeded web app in native FMX app (ios / android) via TWebBrowser.

All works ok, except Window.print. I use PDF js for viewer and print

if I use web app directly on safari / chrome printing PDF works ok.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, any option for enable printing ?